# Couldn't able to Update the data in CRUD using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm Practising CRUD in AJAX and JQuery I Sorted out How to add and get data from Database using ADO but Couldn't able to update the datas in the crud ned some help!!

> ## This my HomeController.cs

this where every function for the program will be written here

```
 using CRUDAjax.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    
    namespace CRUDAjax.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
           
            EmployeeDB empDB = new EmployeeDB();
            // GET: Home  
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            public JsonResult List()
            {
                return Json(empDB.ListAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            public JsonResult Add(Employee emp)
            {
                return Json(empDB.Add(emp), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            public JsonResult GetbyID(int ID)
            {
                var Employee = empDB.ListAll().Find(x => x.EmployeeID.Equals(ID));
                return Json(Employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            public JsonResult Update(Employee emp)
            {
                return Json(empDB.Update(emp), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
            {
                return Json(empDB.Delete(ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

> ## Employee.cs Model

this is the model for the employee details

```
 using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Web;
     
    namespace CRUDAjax.Models {
     public class Employee { public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    
            public string Name { get; set; }
        
            public int Age { get; set; }
        
            public string State { get; set; }
        
            public string Country { get; set; }
        }
    
    }
    
    }
```

> ## EmployeeDB.cs Model

Here the Database Connection Will be Given and here i used ADO method(Connection String)

```
using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Configuration;
     using System.Data;
     using System.Data.SqlClient;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;

 

    > namespace CRUDAjax.Models  {  
public class EmployeeDB  {



     string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"\].ConnectionString;

  

  >
    >         //Return list of all Employees  
    >         public List\<Employee\> ListAll()
    >         {
    >             List\<Employee\> lst = new List\<Employee\>();
    >             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    >             {
    >                 con.Open();
    >                 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SelectEmployee", con);
    >                 com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    >                 SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
    >                 while (rdr.Read())
    >                 {
    >                     lst.Add(new Employee
    >                     {
    >                         EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr\["EmployeeId"\]),
    >                         Name = rdr\["Name"\].ToString(),
    >                         Age = Convert.ToInt32(rdr\["Age"\]),
    >                         State = rdr\["State"\].ToString(),
    >                         Country = rdr\["Country"\].ToString(),
    >                     });
    >                 }
    >                 return lst;
    >             }
    >         }
    >     
    >         //Method for Adding an Employee  
    >         public int Add(Employee emp)
    >         {
    >             int i;
    >             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    >             {
    >                 con.Open();
    >                 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdateEmployee", con);
    >                 com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", emp.EmployeeID);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", emp.Name);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", emp.Age);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", emp.State);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", emp.Country);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Insert");
    >                 i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    >             }
    >             return i;
    >         }
    >     
    >         //Method for Updating Employee record  
    >         public int Update(Employee emp)
    >         {
    >             int i;
    >             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    >             {
    >                 con.Open();
    >                 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdateEmployee", con);
    >                 com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", emp.EmployeeID);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", emp.Name);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", emp.Age);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", emp.State);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", emp.Country);
    >                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Update");
    >                 i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    >             }
    >             return i;
    >         }
    >     
    >         //Method for Deleting an Employee  
    >         public int Delete(int ID)
    >         {
    >             int i;
    >             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    >             {
    >                 con.Open();
    >                 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DeleteEmployee", con);
                     com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ID);
                     i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
                 return i;
    >         }
    >     }
    >
    > }
```

> ## employee.js (ajax and jquery functions)
>
> This the javascript where the Ajax Functions of the CRUD where will be written

```
  \`//Load Data in Table when documents is ready  
    > $(document).ready(function () {
    > loadData();
    > });
    >
    > //Load Data function  
    > function loadData() {
    > $.ajax({
    > url: "/Home/List",
    > type: "GET",
    > contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    > dataType: "json",
    > success: function (result) {
    > var html = '';
    > $.each(result, function (key, item) {
    > html += '\<tr\>';
    > html += '\<td\>' + item.EmployeeID + '\</td\>';
    > html += '\<td\>' + item.Name + '\</td\>';
    > html += '\<td\>' + item.Age + '\</td\>';
    > html += '\<td\>' + item.State + '\</td\>';
    > html += '\<td\>' + item.Country + '\</td\>';
    > html += '\<td\><a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>\</td\>';
    > html += '\</tr\>';
    > });
    > $('.tbody').html(html);
    > },
    > error: function (errormessage) {
    > alert(errormessage.responseText);
    > }
    > });
    > }
    >
    > //Add Data Function  
    > function Add() {
    >
    >     var empObj = {
    >         EmployeeID: $('#EmployeeID').val(),
    >         Name: $('#Name').val(),
    >         Age: $('#Age').val(),
    >         State: $('#State').val(),
    >         Country: $('#Country').val()
    >     };
    >     $.ajax({
    >         url: "/Home/Add",
    >         data: JSON.stringify(empObj),
    >         type: "POST",
    >         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    >         dataType: "json",
    >         success: function (result) {
    >             loadData();
    >             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    >         },
    >         error: function (errormessage) {
    >             alert(errormessage.responseText);
    >         }
    >     });
    >
    > }
    >
    >     //Function for getting the Data Based upon Employee IDfunction getbyID(EmpID) {$('#Name').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$('#Age').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$('#State').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$('#Country').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$.ajax({url: "/Home/getbyID/" + EmpID,type: "GET",contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",dataType: "json",success: function (result) {$('#EmployeeID').val(result.EmployeeID);$('#Name').val(result.Name);$('#Age').val(result.Age);$('#State').val(result.State);$('#Country').val(result.Country);
    >
    >             $('#myModal').modal('show');
    >             $('#btnUpdate').show();
    >             $('#btnAdd').hide();
    >         },
    >         error: function (errormessage) {
    >             alert(errormessage.responseText);
    >         }
    >     });
    >     return false;
    >
    > }
    >
    > //function for updating employee's record  
    > function Update() {
    >
    >     var empObj = {
    >         EmployeeID: $('#EmployeeID').val(),
    >         Name: $('#Name').val(),
    >         Age: $('#Age').val(),
    >         State: $('#State').val(),
    >         Country: $('#Country').val(),
    >     };
    >     $.ajax({
    >         url: "/Home/Update",
    >         data: JSON.stringify(empObj),
    >         type: "POST",
    >         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    >         dataType: "json",
    >         success: function (result) {
    >             loadData();
    >             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    >             $('#EmployeeID').val("");
    >             $('#Name').val("");
    >             $('#Age').val("");
    >             $('#State').val("");
    >             $('#Country').val("");
    >     
    >         },
    >         error: function (errormessage) {
    >             alert(errormessage.responseText);
    >         }
    >     });
    >
    > }
    
    >     //function for deleting employee's recordfunction Delete(ID) {var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");if (ans) {$.ajax({url: "/Home/Delete/" + ID,type: "POST",contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",dataType: "json",success: function (result) {loadData();},error: function (errormessage) {alert(errormessage.responseText);}});}}
    >
    >     //Function for clearing the textboxesfunction clearTextBox() {$('#EmployeeID').val("");$('#Name').val("");$('#Age').val("");$('#State').val("");$('#Country').val("");$('#btnUpdate').hide();$('#btnAdd').show();$('#Name').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$('#Age').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$('#State').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');$('#Country').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');}//Valdidation using jqueryfunction validate() {var isValid = true;if ($('#Name').val().trim() == "") {$('#Name').css('border-color', 'Red');isValid = false;}else {$('#Name').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');}if ($('#Age').val().trim() == "") {$('#Age').css('border-color', 'Red');isValid = false;}else {$('#Age').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');}if ($('#State').val().trim() == "") {$('#State').css('border-color', 'Red');isValid = false;}else {$('#State').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');}if ($('#Country').val().trim() == "") {$('#Country').css('border-color', 'Red');isValid = false;}else {$('#Country').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');}return isValid;}`
```

> ## index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
@*<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/employee.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Employees Record</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="clearTextBox();">Add New Employee</button><br /><br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
                <th>
                    State
                </th>
                <th>
                    Country
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="EmployeeId">ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmployeeID" placeholder="Id" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="EmployeeName">EmployeeName</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="EmployeeName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Age">Age</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Age" placeholder="Age" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="EmployeeState">EmployeeState</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="EmployeeState" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Country">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Add();">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdate" style="display:none;" onclick="Update();">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
@*<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

By updating The scripts i sorted it out!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use breakpoints to diagnose which of the following is the problem:

1. Is the API not called? (Error code?)
   -> Specify 'Http Method' in the controller.
   -> e.g.)

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult List()
   {
       return Json(empDB.ListAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```

2) Does the API call work, but no parameters come in?
-> Use another tool(e.g. chrome developer tools) to check if parameters are being passed.

-> If that doesn't work, specify the type of the parameter.
e.g. )

```
public JsonResult Add([FromForm] Employee emp)
```

3) Is DB select (or update) not possible?
-> Search for the message in the error window and correct the error.

Comment: i tried but the error is from GETID function 
even though used the BreakPoints its not hitting the update function and looping inside select procedure as it's a list 
and not popping up the modal for update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. 
Are you referring to the 'GetbyID' method? 
Problems with 'ListAll()'? 
Is there a result of 'ListAll()'?

Comment: Thank You !!!
My senior sorted It Out!!

the  problem is in the script and the bootstrap section
After refering some articles he updated that